# replace value between pattern

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I have below string, I am able to grab the 'text' what I wanted to (text is warped between pattern). code is give below,

```
val1 = '[{&quot;vmdId&quot;:&quot;Text1&quot;,&quot;vmdVersion&quot;:&quot;text2&quot;,&quot;vmId&quot;:&quot;text3&quot;},{&quot;vmId&quot;:&quot;text4&quot;,&quot;vmVersion&quot;:&quot;text5&quot;,&quot;vmId&quot;:&quot;text6&quot;}]'


temp = val1.split(',')
list_len =  len(temp)

for i in range(0, list_len):
    var = temp[i]
    found = re.findall(r':&quot;([^(]*)\&quot\;', var)
    print ''.join(found)
```

I would like to replace values (Text1, text2, tex3, etc) with new values provided by user / or by reading from another XML. (Text1, tex2 .. are is totally random and alphanumeric data.

For more info, yesterday I posted this question, but it was useful however it was appending `'new'` to existing text, and that was not my requirement. May be I was not able to convey properly. 
[python to search and update string with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772698/python-to-search-and-update-string-with-regex/46772919#46772919)

Once I decided to go with `replace()` but later realize data is not constant. hence seeking for help again. Appreciate your response.

Need your help on how this.

Comment: It is exactly the same task. Please go to the original question, add details you failed to convey before, add expected output to the question, drop a comment under the answer you got that the solution is not working for you and *why*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Will do that ..! Thanks !